# What is domination ranking?

Tags: mm-heroes-kingdoms

In the online game Might and Magic: Heroes Kingdoms there is something called Domination ranking. What is it and how do I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Domination is based on the cumulated power of your armies, the value of your city's buildings and regional buildings.